# Xorg freezing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 18.04, freeze, gdm

I have a notebook with a clean install of Ubuntu 18.04, no updates, no garbage, I formatted my notebook and installed the OS.

Always when do "some things" (I'll explain) i can see in $ `htop` the process Xorg go to 99% of CPU usage. It is freezing for about 5 seconds and but is necessary to annoy me.

these "things" thats trigges the freeze is:

- focus / select any Password field, i tested on lock screen, firefox, Steam etc.
- use any "<kbd>Fn</kbd> + button" like Volume + or Volume-, mousepad on / off, etc.
- use any number of the numpad keyboard
- I have a mouse Razer naga Classic, and it has a numpad, when I press that's key the so freeze too

I tryed a world of fix i found in the internet like:

- reconfigure xserver-xorg
- make the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`
- kill the process
- uninstall driver nvidia
- while withouth the nvidia driver, reinstall of Ubuntu-drivers
- downgrade of the nvidia drivers
- reconfigure the gdm / gdm3 idk the difference.
- tryed to use the wayland, but i dont know how
- tryed Unity, Ubuntu, Ubuntu gnome
- I notice gnome was some incompatibilities with Remote Access softwares, so I uninstall teamviewer
- The files `~/.xsession-errors` and `/var/log/gdm/:0.log` not exist
- The log file of Xorg `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` not log when i force the freeze

For some additional information:

`dmesg` output: https://pastebin.com/xjPVe7Fd

`Xorg.0.log` output: https://pastebin.com/2GnZD0MK

in the end of the day, the problem is alive.
I search for some tips for I log or debug this problem

Thanks.

Comment: The two first file not exist Yah, and the dmesg havent any tip.

Comment: Today i reinstalled the ubuntu 18.04, and the error continues. I'm almost giving up.

Comment: David, the output of `dmesg`: https://pastebin.com/xjPVe7Fd the others doest not exist.

Comment: the Modified Date of the Xorg.0.log is not altered when i force the freeze, but the output is here:  https://pastebin.com/2GnZD0MK

Comment: no, and nothing from the /var/log path

Comment: Sure, Thanks David.
if i find the solution i come back here.